# Remove extra bottom padding when using Accompanist Insets library in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, insets, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have a column, containing TextFields, and a button at the bottom of the screen.

I'm trying to make the Column scrollable so that I can scroll down to see the button that hides behind the keyboard when that opens.

My Column looks like this.

```
        Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
            .nestedScroll(connection = rememberImeNestedScrollConnection())
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {...}
```

If i put `navigationBarsWithImePadding()` the Column scrolls but adds some extra padding at the bottom which I don't want. There's some component named Crossfade which occupies the bottom part of the screen.

[image]

And if I remove it, it doesn't scroll anymore.

I think I'm doing something wrong. Any tips would be appreciated.